# Outlook shows some headers in mail body (php mail)

Tags: php, email, outlook

Does anybody have idea why Outlook shows part of the headers in the mail body of a plain-text email that is sent with php's mail() function? Thunderbird on the other hand shows the email correctly.

These are the headers from the email source:

```
Return-Path: <user@mydomain.com>
X-Original-To: webmaster@mydomain.com
Delivered-To: webmaster@mydomain.com
Received: by mydomain.com (Postfix, from userid 10001)
id C7C0C4563746; Sat, 22 Mar 2014 03:11:19 +0200 (EET)
To: =?UTF-8?B?U2VuZGVy?= <webmaster@mydomain.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgdGl0bGU=?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 10001:sendmail.php
From: =?UTF-8?B?U2VuZGVy?= <webmaster@mydomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Message-Id: <20140322011119.C7C0C4563746@mydomain.com>
Date: Sat, 22 Mar 2014 03:11:19 +0200 (EET)
```

... and these lines are shown in the beginning of the mail body in Outlook 2007:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Message-Id: <20140322011119.C7C0C4563746@mydomain.com>
Date: Sat, 22 Mar 2014 03:11:19 +0200 (EET)
```

The only headers that are defined in the code are:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

The problem can be solved by excluding these, which is AFAIK against the recommended way of using php's mail() function. Or is it? Should I just drop the MIME, content-type and charset or is there a better way?

BTW, the problem appears only on a server that uses PHP 5.3.3. This server also seems to handle newlines differently ("\r\n" causes two line breaks in Outlook) compared to my other test servers that use PHP versions 5.3.27 (WAMP) and 5.4.3 - these don't have the header problem either. The line break problem in the message body was solved by replacing "\r\n" with PHP_EOL - tried it on the $headers too but without success.

Comment: Make sure you're consistently using '\r\n' as your line endings; that's what is required for SMTP.  The usual reason headers show up in the body is due to an extra line ending somewhere in the headers.  Some email clients will be more forgiving, but closer your code sticks to the spec the better off you'll be.

Comment: Given where it  breaks for you, I'd check the format of the text of the "From:" email address.

Comment: Thanks Joe for pointing to the right place. I thought I had checked that as well but that was the only place in the headers where I had forgotten to test replacing "\r\n" with PHP_EOL. So it turns out that for an unknown reason this server seems to add that extra line whenever "\r\n" is being used. Still it seems odd that the problem exists only on one server and only on Outlook...